# Обращение к компонентам другой формы

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется 2 формы: главная и форма, создаваемая по нажатию на radioButton. На главной форме имеется textBox, а на второй форме - кнопка. Вопрос: как мне сделать так, чтобы по нажатию кнопки на второй форме, менялось содержимое textBox на первой? Куда мне нужно передать главную форму?

Comment: C# не имеет кнопок. Указывайте правильно метки вопросов. C# - это всего лишь язык программирования.

Comment: Заведите event на второй форме и вызывайте его на нажатие кнопки. А главная форма назначит обработчик этого события и сама поменяет что следует в своих компонентах.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Пример написания]

попробуйте так, только у обьекта к которому обращаетесь поставьте модификатор Public

Comment: `= yourForm()` - шикарный синтаксис. Не то.

Comment: 1. сделайте модификатор обьекта к которому вы хотите обратиться "Public". 
2. Объявите форму в классе допустим: ( Form1 form1 = new Form1();)
3. Далее уже обращаетесь к этой форме

Comment: Плохая идея. 1.Не рекомендовано объектам делать модификатор доступа public. 2. Создавая во второй экземпляр первой формы через конструктор вы не получите ссылку на первую форму (уж лучше в конструктор второй формы добавить параметр типа form1 и передавать в него this при создании второй формы.

Comment: @OlegKlezovich согласен с вами

Answer (score 0):

В общем, я за то, чтобы делать так, как Вам указали в комментариях. А именно:

```
//form1
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ...
    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
        f2.Show();
    }
    public void ChangeTextInTextBox(string newText)
    {
        textBox1.Text = newText;
    }
}
//form2
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public delegate void ChangeTextBox(string nText);
    public event ChangeTextBox ChangeTextBox1;


    public Form2(Form1 f1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ChangeTextBox1 += f1.ChangeTextInTextBox;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeTextBox1("New Text");
    }
}
```

По мне так кратко и достаточно красиво, и вроде как не нарушает принципов ООП.