# Как создать, а потом обратится к элементу другой формы?

Tags: c#, winforms, form

Мне нужно, что бы при нажатии на кнопку, находящейся на первой форме создавался элемент на другой форме. А так же нужно обратится к свойствам этого элемента (всё по нажатию той одной кнопки).

Comment: [30 секунд поиска](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/463557/373567)

Comment: Не сомневайтесь я искал. И да, я видел эту запись, однако я всё равно не понимаю как создать к примеру picturebox на другой форме с помощью кнопки на первой форме. А потом тут же изменить его свойства.
В записи описано только про обращение, а я создать элемент не могу.

Comment: [Классы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes), [Объекты](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/objects), [Поля](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields), [Свойства](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties).

Answer (score 0):

Вот простой пример динамического создания формы, добавления на неё кнопки, и обработки события нажатия на эту кнопку

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Form newForm = new Form(); // Создаём экземпляр класса Form

            // Создаём экземпляр класса Button которая будет помещена на форму
            Button newButton = new Button {
                Width = 150,
                Text = "Кнопка на новой ворме"
            };
            
            newButton.Location = new Point {
                X = (newForm.ClientSize.Width / 2 - newButton.Width / 2),
                Y = (newForm.ClientSize.Height / 2 - newButton.Height / 2)
            };

            // Добавляем обработчик события нажатия на эту енопку и описываем её действия (гугли "Лямбда в C#")
            newButton.Click += (se, ea) => { MessageBox.Show("Событие для кнопки на новой ворме"); };

            // Добавляем кнопку в список контролов формы
            newForm.Controls.Add(newButton);

            // Показываем форму
            newForm.Show();
        }
```